# Snow Leopard with Cisco VPN won't turn off split tunneling

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, cisco, osx-snow-leopard

I have noticed when connecting to my office via my MacBook Pro that I'm able to access both the office network and my home network, in other words split-tunneling is turned on.  We have explicityly disallowed this on the hardware side.

This occurs using either the Cisco VPN client that is built-in, or one I installed after the fact.  Has anyone else experienced this?

I'm wondering if this is a known issue or if there's something I'm not configuring correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same 'problem' here.

Comment: Are you by any chance accessing local resources using ipv6?

Comment: I like your thinking Helvick.  I certainly could be, but I'm more of a Windows expert so I'm not sure where to look for that on a Mac.  I'll try digging around to find out, but do you know how I could find that information?

Comment: I've found that i can still access servers on my local lan while connected to a Cisco VPN by using their bonjour name. Such as; server.local I have the Cisco client setup under Snow Leopard and I am not experiencing the same 'problem' as you when trying to access local server by their FQDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a separate setting for "Allow local LAN access", which is what you're describing -- this isn't quite the same thing as split tunneling. Split tunneling will use your non-tunneled default gateway to reach things that aren't explicitly in a list of tunneled networks. A better test would be if you go to, say, [http://whatismyipaddress.com/](http://whatismyipaddress.com) and it shows your home network's IP, then you're really split-tunnel.

Comment: Thanks, good explanation.  I did see my corporate IP address when I went to that site, and that makes sense.